# Javascript function not executing properly when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <form>

                <table id="pulseputtable">
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <label>Pulse rate : </label>
                        <input id="rate" type=text  placeholder="xxx"> per minute <br><br>

                        <select id="age" name=age>
                                <option value="age1">0-12 months</option>                               
                                <option value="age2">1-18 years</option>
                                <option value="age3">18+ years</option>
                            </select>
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="button" value="Check"   onclick="pulse()">                         
                        <br><br>

                             <label id = "check"></label>


                    </td>   
                </tr>
            </table>




        </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">


         function pulse(){
         var c = document.getElementById("age");
         var age = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
        var rate =  document.getElementById("rate");

        switch(age){
            case "age1":
                if((rate>=115) && (rate<=130)){
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Normal";
                }
                else if(( rate<115)){
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Too low";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Too High";
                }

                break;    

            case "age2":
                    if((rate>=80) && (rate<=115)){
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Normal";
                    }
                else if(( rate<80)){
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Too low";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Too High";
                }

                break;   


            case "age3":
                        if((rate>=60) && (rate<=80)){
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Normal";
                        }
                else if(( rate<60)){
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Too low";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Too High";
                }

                break;  
                        }
                    }


    </script>





    </body>




</html>
```

My intention of this code is to call the pulse() function when i click the button but it does not work. Aim of the code is to input the pulse rate of a person into the text field and select an age category! After clicking the button a result should be displayed in the label based on the condtions given in the javascript function! please help me ive been hanging on this for hours! :(

Comment: You have syntax errors and typos all over the place. `if( rate<115))` for example, or `esle` when you mean `else`.  Check your error console.

Comment: corrected still its not working :(

Comment: I'm sure there are more. Check your error console.

Comment: how to check? i am using adobe brackets?

Comment: In the web browser, open developer tools, look at the console.

Comment: Opened how to detect any errors in the code after that?

Comment: Error messages will appear in the console when you load the page or run the script.   You should get in the habit of leaving that open while you're working; and you should *definitely* check it before posting questions here.

Comment: no error message bro

Comment: That is not possible, given that I can see at least a half-dozen typos and mis-nested brackets in your code.  You must be looking in the wrong place. This will depend on which browser you're using; there is plenty of information on how to use the console available. Google.

Comment: i corrected all of them still its not working

Comment: Ok... one more issue that leaps out: `var rate` is referring to a DOM element, you want its value.

Comment: Thanx bro that was the issue! it was a great help

Answer (score -2):

The last else block in each case statement is having typo error. In place of else you are having esle. Correct the typo error and it should work fine....

Comment: there are several syntax errors all over the place and this doesnt cover all the problems posed by this question.

Comment: var c = document.getElementById("age");
        var rate =  document.getElementById("rate");
in the above lines try to get the value of it and in switch staements..
var rate =  document.getElementById("rate").value;

Comment: whats the mistake there?